# How to access data in my razor view from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

in my mvc razor view, I have these codes:

```
@if (Model != null) {

       if (Model.Meals != null)
         {
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Meals, defaultSort: "MDate");

   double Total = Model.Meals.Where(x => x.FINtravelID == Model.FINtravelID).Sum( t =>t.MTAmount);
```

And in the script header, I need to get the data of "Total" above in this code:

```
$(function () {

            $("#grid tbody").append('<tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td><b>' + Total.toFixed(2) + '</b> </td></tr>');
    })
```

I have tried to add @ in front of Total, but it does not compile, anybody kow how to make it working?

Comment: I added the code in side of <script> with $ started, I think you can say it jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to retrieve `Total` outside of the code block unless you nest it within an element or a hidden input and then retrieved that data with JS. So, for example, if your code looked like this:

```
@if (Model != null) 
{
    if (Model.Meals != null)
    {
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Meals, defaultSort: "MDate");

        double Total = Model.Meals.Where(x => x.FINtravelID == Model.FINtravelID).Sum( t =>t.MTAmount);
        <div id="Total">@Total</div>
    }
}
```

You could grab the data with JS, but you will need to cast the value as a number in order to use the isFixed() method on it because JS implicitly types as string. So use Number() to convert string => double:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var total = Number(document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML).toFixed(2);

    $("#grid tbody").append('<tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td><b>' + total + '</b> </td></tr>');
});
</script>
```